# How to design a main list and sublists schema

Tags: database-design

I am finding it difficult to design a database schema for a list feature. there would be a master list which then can be subsectioned into further lists.

each user is able to mark a candidate as a favourite candidate and can have many favourite candidates.

if a candidate is deleted from a list then it should still remain part of favourites, or be part of the main favoirtes list without belonging to a particular list.

- a user can mark many candidates as favourite
- a user can have many favourites lists
- a favourites list can have many candidates

the following is what I have come up with so far.
[image]
as shown in the above image I am allowing the FavouritesListId to be nullable, this way if a list item is not associated with a certain list this means it is still favourited but not part of a particular list. I want to know if this is the optimal solution or if there is a better design approach available.

and here is the script to the schema:

```
    USE [Favourites]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Candidates]    Script Date: 10/05/2015 18:43:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Candidates](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Candidates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FavouritesList]    Script Date: 10/05/2015 18:43:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FavouritesList](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FavouritesList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FavouritesListItem]    Script Date: 10/05/2015 18:43:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FavouritesListItem](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FavouritesListId] [int] NULL,
    [CandidateId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FavouritesListItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Users]    Script Date: 10/05/2015 18:43:52 ******/
```

Comment: Will the favourite lists be shared among users or each user will have his own lists?

Comment: @ypercube each user will have its own lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I have with your current model is that it would be possible for a FavouritesList to contain FavouritesListItems that belong to different Users, which to my understanding of your business logic shouldn't happen. I think a better way would be to store all FavouritesListItems that don't belong to a particular FavouritesList in some entity that is designated as a User's "UngroupedFavouritesList". There are a few ways to create that entity.

## Method 1

Make the Title attribute in FavouritesList nullable. If it is null, then it is considered to be the User's "UngroupedFavouritesList".
[image]

## Method 2

Add an "isUngrouped" flag to the FavouritesList table. If it's set to true, the it's considered the User's "UngroupedFavouritesList". The title attribute of FavouritesList would be null in this case.
[image]

## Method 3

Make FavouritesList a parent table with UngroupedFavouritesList and NamedFavouritesList as child tables. This is achieved by having the primary key of UngroupedFavouritesList and NamedFavouritesList also be a foreign key to the FavouritesList's primary key.
[image]

## Method 4

Create an "IFavouritesContainer" interface table, which both FavouritesList and User implement. This is achieved by User and FavouritesList having a foreign key to the IFavouritesContainer table. The FavouritesListItem then has a reference to the IFavouritesContainer that contains it. For ungrouped list items, its IFavouritesContainer would be the User. Note that the idea of implementing interfaces isn't a built-in thing with any RDMS that I know of, I'm just using the terms as an analogy to object oriented programming.
[image]

## Pros and Cons for each method

- Method 1
          Pros:

  - Simple

  Cons:

  - It's not obvious that a null title means it's an "UngroupedFavouritesList
  - It's possible for a User to have multiple "UngroupedFavouritesLists"
- Method 2
          Pros:

  - Simple
  - Clear what is an "UngroupedFavouritesList" and what isn't

  Cons:

  - Storing a title for the "UngroupedFavouritesList", even though it will always be null. This is very minor.
  - It's possible for a User to have multiple "UngroupedFavouritesLists"
- Method 3
          Pros:

  - Clear what is an "UngroupedFavouritesList" and what isn't
  - Tables don't contain unnecessary fields

  Cons:

  - It's possible for a User to have multiple "UngroupedFavouritesLists"
  - More complex
- Method 4
          Pros:
  Tables don't contain unnecessary fields
- The business logic of a User containing only one "UngroupedFavouritesList" but multiple "NamedFavouritesLists" is preserved

Cons:

- More complex
- Not obvious what it means for a FavouritesListItem to be contained by Users vs FavouritesList